# Why is my UITableView Cell not Pushing to The detail View Controller when tapped

Tags: swift, uikit

so Im making a twitter clone in UIKit and Im trying to allow a user to tap on the tweet to see more details about it put when ever I tap on the tweet it never pushes to the detailed view called TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController. im going to post the code for the tableView and show my storyBoard.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq0BD.png])

[image]

[image]

I tried making sure I set everything up in storyBard and everything there seems fine. but I did notice when ever I set the the tableView itself to the initial view controller it would push to the detailView...

here's the tableView code

```
struct Tweet {
    
    let name: String
    let message: String
    let profileImageName: String
    let title: String
    let userName: String
    let comments: String
    let numberOfComments: Int
    let retweet: String
    let numberOfRetweets: Int
    let likes: String
    let numberOfLikes: Int
    let views: String
    let numberOfViews: Int
    let share: String
    
 
   }



class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let userNameLabel = UILabel()
    let commentsLabel = UIButton()
    
   

    
        

    let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
    let retweetsLabel = UIButton()
    let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
    let likesLabel = UIButton()
    let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
    let viewsLabel = UIButton()
    let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
    let shareLabel = UIButton()
    
    
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        commentsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfCommentsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        retweetsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfRetweetsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        likesLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfLikesLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfViewsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shareLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        commentsLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCommentsLabel), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        /*
    
         let commentsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
         let retweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let likesLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
         let viewsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
         let shareLabel = UILabel()
         */
        
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(commentsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(numberOfCommentsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(retweetsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(numberOfRetweetsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(likesLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(numberOfLikesLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(viewsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(numberOfViewsLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(shareLabel)
        
    
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: -16),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -50),
            
            userNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 243),
            userNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 167),
            userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            
            messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -45),
            messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            commentsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            commentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 13),
            
            numberOfCommentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            numberOfCommentsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            retweetsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 19),
            retweetsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
           numberOfRetweetsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: retweetsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            numberOfRetweetsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            likesLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 107),
            likesLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            numberOfLikesLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentsLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 183),
            numberOfLikesLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            viewsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 195),
            viewsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            numberOfViewsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 228),
            numberOfViewsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            
            shareLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberOfCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 276),
            shareLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
            
            /*
             
             let commentsLabel = UILabel()
             let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
             let retweetsLabel = UILabel()
             let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
             let likesLabel = UILabel()
             let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
             let viewsLabel = UILabel()
             let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
             let shareLabel = UILabel()
             */
            
            
        ])
        
        // Set the corner radius of the image view
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
           
    @objc func didTapCommentsLabel() {
          // Handle the tap event here
        
        print("Jam")
      }


    
    
    func configure(with tweet: Tweet) {
        
        nameLabel.text = tweet.name
        messageLabel.text = tweet.message
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: tweet.profileImageName)
        titleLabel.text = tweet.title
        userNameLabel.text = tweet.userName
       
        commentsLabel.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "message"), for: .normal)
        commentsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfCommentsLabel.text = "\(tweet.numberOfComments)"
        retweetsLabel.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "repeat"), for: .normal)
        numberOfRetweetsLabel.text = "\(tweet.numberOfRetweets)"
        likesLabel.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart"), for: .normal)
        numberOfLikesLabel.text = "\(tweet.numberOfLikes)"
        viewsLabel.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill"), for: .normal)
        numberOfViewsLabel.text = "\(tweet.numberOfViews)"
        shareLabel.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill"), for: .normal)
        
        
    }
    // the amount right amount of things that has to be able
    
}


class twitterHomeFeedTableView: UITableViewController {
    
    
    let twitterLogoImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "twitterLogo"))
    let addTweetbutton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 130, width: 89, height: 64))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        /*
         
         let commentsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
         let retweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let likesLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
         let viewsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
         let shareLabel = UILabel()
         */
        
        tabBarController?.delegate = self
        
        tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tweetCell")
        
        
        // Set the delegate of the UITabBarController to self
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        twitterLogoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addTweetbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        
        /*
         
         let commentsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
         let retweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let likesLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
         let viewsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
         let shareLabel = UILabel()
         */
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            //   tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            //   tableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            //   tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            //   tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            //   twitterLogoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            ///  twitterLogoImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            //  twitterLogoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 59),
            //  twitterLogoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34),
            
            //  addTweetbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            //  addTweetbutton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 70),
            //  addTweetbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 89),
            // addTweetbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64)
        ])
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets.count
    }
    
    
    let tweets: [Tweet] = [
        
        Tweet(name: "Karon Bell", message: "Just had the best pizza ever ", profileImageName: "kb", title: "", userName: "@karonbell", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 44, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 63, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 73, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI"),
        Tweet(name: "NBA", message: "Can't wait to go on vacation next week ", profileImageName: "nba", title: "", userName: "@nba", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 21, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 23, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 23, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI"),
        Tweet(name: "Google", message: "Finished my first marathon today! ‍♀️", profileImageName: "google", title: "", userName: "@google", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 21, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 23, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 23, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI"),
        Tweet(name: "Mark Zuck", message: "facebook is my day job ", profileImageName: "markkk", title: "", userName: "@marky", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 21, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 23, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 23, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI"),
        Tweet(name: "Elon Musk", message: "I love this app can you tell?", profileImageName: "elom", title: "", userName: "@elonMusk", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 21, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 23, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 23, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI"),
        Tweet(name: "justin Bieber", message: "will you be my Baby?♥️", profileImageName: "jb", title: "", userName: "@justinBieber", comments: "KUOH", numberOfComments: 21, retweet: "KIHUOL", numberOfRetweets: 23, likes: "IKUHU", numberOfLikes: 23, views: "KUHO", numberOfViews: 54, share: "IHLPHI")
        
        
        /*
         
         let commentsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfCommentsLabel = UILabel()
         let retweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfRetweetsLabel = UILabel()
         let likesLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfLikesLabel = UILabel()
         let viewsLabel = UILabel()
         let numberOfViewsLabel = UILabel()
         let shareLabel = UILabel()
         */
        
        
        
    ]
    
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tweetCell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue TweetTableViewCell")
        }
        
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: tweet)
        return cell
        
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController {
            vc.selectedTweet = tweets[indexPath.row].message
            
            // Check if the detail view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller
            if let navVC = vc.navigationController {
                navVC.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            } else {
                // If not, embed it in a new navigation controller and present it
                let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            
            print("Pushed")
        } else {
            print("failed")
        }
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 111
    }
    
    
   
}

extension twitterHomeFeedTableView: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Check if the selected view controller belongs to the "For you" tab
        if let currentViewController = self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController,
           currentViewController.tabBarItem.title == "Following" {
            // Reload the table view data if the current view controller is the "For you" tab
            tableView.reloadData()
            print("JGHV")
        }
        
    }
}



and here's the code for the tabBar in my app as well




class TwitterHomePage: UIViewController {

    var currentLineView: UIView?

    let tableViewContainer = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

     

        
        let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController()
        tabBarController.delegate = self

        let forYouTabBarItem = CustomTabBarItem(
            title: "For you",
            image: UIImage(named: "forYouImage"),
            selectedImage: UIImage(named: "forYouImageSelected")
        )
        let followingTabBarItem = CustomTabBarItem(
            title: "Following",
            image: UIImage(named: "followingImage"),
            selectedImage: UIImage(named: "followingImageSelected")
        )

        
        let homeViewController = UIViewController()
        homeViewController.tabBarItem = forYouTabBarItem

        let followingViewController = UIViewController()
        followingViewController.tabBarItem = followingTabBarItem

        tabBarController.viewControllers = [homeViewController, followingViewController]

        addChild(tabBarController)

        view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
        tabBarController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tabBarController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 99)
        ])

      
        tableViewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableViewContainer)

        let twitterHomeFeedViewController = twitterHomeFeedTableView(style: .plain)
        addChild(twitterHomeFeedViewController)
        twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableViewContainer.addSubview(twitterHomeFeedViewController.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarController.view.bottomAnchor),
            twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: twitterHomeFeedViewController.view.topAnchor)
        ])

        let twitterLogoImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "twitterLogo"))
        twitterLogoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(twitterLogoImageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            twitterLogoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            twitterLogoImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 97),
            twitterLogoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 59),
            twitterLogoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
        ])

        let addTweetButton = UIButton()
        addTweetButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "addTweet"), for: .normal)
        addTweetButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addTweetButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            addTweetButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 143),
            addTweetButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -25),
            addTweetButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95),
            addTweetButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 77)
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Reload the data in the table view if the "For you" tab bar item is reselected
        if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController,
           tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0,
           let navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController,
           navigationController.topViewController is twitterHomeFeedTableView {
            if let tableView = (navigationController.topViewController as? twitterHomeFeedTableView)?.tableView {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

}



extension TwitterHomePage: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Remove any existing blue line views
        currentLineView?.removeFromSuperview()
        
        // Check if the selected view controller is the one for the "For you" tab bar item
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
            // Show the table view container
            tableViewContainer.isHidden = false
            
            // Reload the data in the table view
            if let twitterHomeFeedVC = viewController as? twitterHomeFeedTableView {
                twitterHomeFeedVC.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
            // Add a blue line below the selected tab bar item
            let itemWidth = tabBarController.tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBarController.tabBar.items?.count ?? 3)
            let lineWidth: CGFloat = 165
            let lineX = itemWidth * CGFloat(tabBarController.selectedIndex) + (itemWidth - lineWidth) / 2
            let lineY = tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height - 0
            
            let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: lineX, y: lineY, width: lineWidth, height: 2))
            lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
            tabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
            
            // Keep a reference to the current line view
            currentLineView = lineView
        } else {
            // Hide the table view container
            tableViewContainer.isHidden = true
            
            // Add a blue line below the selected tab bar item
            let itemWidth = tabBarController.tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBarController.tabBar.items?.count ?? 3)
            let lineWidth: CGFloat = 165
            let lineX = itemWidth * CGFloat(tabBarController.selectedIndex) + (itemWidth - lineWidth) / 2
            let lineY = tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height - 0
            
            let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: lineX, y: lineY, width: lineWidth, height: 2))
            lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
            tabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
            
            // Keep a reference to the current line view
            currentLineView = lineView
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you have UserInteractionEnabled for TableView or Cell.

Comment: Is it printing `print("Pushed")` this  **"Pushed"**? If not then make sure you are putting the right instantiate vc identifier .

Comment: it always prints failed

Comment: That means you have some problem in `if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController {` this line.. From storyboard identity inspector change the Storyboard ID of **TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController** to **detail** .. it will work for sure.

Comment: @Karonbell use `self.storyboard` instead of `storyboard`. and make sure same storyboard you are using.

Comment: heres my github for a twitter clone im making https://github.com/imjusttrynabelikeElon/twitter/tree/main  .  ive been trying to push to the detailViewController once a user taps on a tweet for the longest put I don't know why its not pushing. I dont know if its a bug in my code or if the constraints are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting it to see where the error actually happens?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVCID")
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Then you could see what exactly fails.